# spring boot rest keeps looping

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

My method in my rest controller keeps looping.

The method is supposed to get a project from the Mongo database then call another API to get some data and save it again in mongo. It works but it just keeps looping

I use retrofit for my API calls and the application uses spring boot

This is the method that keeps looping
If you need something else just ask me

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/projects/{id}",method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void updateCampaign(@PathVariable String id) throws IOException {
    Project p = projectRepository.findProjectById(id);

    Call<ResponseIndie> get = service.getAllFromCampaign(p.getIndiegogoCampaignId(),API_KEY);
    ResponseIndie responseIndie =get.execute().body();

    IndiegogoCampaign campaign = responseIndie.getIndiegogoCampaign();
    p.setIndiegogoCampaignId(campaign.getId());
    p.setIndiegogoCampaign(campaign);
    projectRepository.save(p);
    logger.info("project saved");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by looping? Where loop occurs?

Comment: When the method is done it goes trough a lot of other classes that are in spring like InvocableHandlerMethod, ServletInvocableHandlerMethod, RequestMappingHandlerAdapter, AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter and DispatcherServlet after that it just starts the method again